# How to show the full image from a drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to show the full image that has been clicked on from my drawer.
I have a liste of images that I display in my drawer and What I want is that when I click on a specific image, it closes my drawer and show the image on my screen in a kind of an image slider where I can switch images directly from the opened image.

here is my code where I extract my list of images from my asset folder :

```
 import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class GetImages extends StatefulWidget {
  const GetImages({super.key});

  @override
  State<GetImages> createState() => _GetImagesState();
}

class _GetImagesState extends State<GetImages> {
  List<String> imagePaths = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    _initImages();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future _initImages() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> assets =
        jsonDecode(await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json'));

    setState(() {
      imagePaths = assets.keys
          .where((String key) => key.contains('photos/'))
          .where((String key) => key.contains('.JPG'))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: constraints.maxWidth > 700 ? 4 : 2,
        children: imagePaths
            .map(
              (path) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 17),
                child: Image.asset(path),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my code for my drawer :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/widgets/get_images.dart';

import 'package:image_viewer/image_viewer.dart';

class SideBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideBar({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('My Page!'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: InkWell(
          child: GetImages(),
          onTap: () {
            //ImageViewer.showImageSlider(images: ["assets/photos/IMG_4100.JPG"]);
            // montre la photo et ferme la sidebar
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this package that i've used before https://pub.dev/packages/lightbox  seems like it does exactly what you are looking for.